# ng-init for select element

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code for ng-init :

```
<select ng-model="yourSelect3"
      class="form-control"
      ng-init="yourSelect3=requirements.Item2[0]"
      ng-options="yourSelect3.StateName for yourSelect3 in requirements.Item2">  
</select>
```

But the initial value is not displayed. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that ng-init does not do what you think it does. It is primarily used in certain cases with ng-select. Angular doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

What you need to do is simply initialize your model in your controller :

```
$scope.yourSelect3 = $scope.requirements.item2[0];
```

Your ng-options is syntactically correct. However, I would recommend that you change your ng-options so that the iterator does not share the name with your model ; this could lead to all sorts of confusion

```
<select ng-model="yourSelect3"
      class="form-control"
      ng-options="item.StateName for item in requirements.Item2">  
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

REWRITE: my previous answer was a little unclear and it missed out a second error.

1st problem: 'yourSelect3' in the ng-options is a 'temp' variable to be used **only in the context of the ng-options**. You can't use this as the ng-model.

2nd problem: in the ng-options you are saying to use the 'StateName' property as the choosen value however your ng-init is trying to assign the whole object as the choosen value.

So...

if you want StateName as the choosenValue use..

```
<select ng-model="choosenValue"
      class="form-control"
      ng-init="choosenValue=requirements.Item2[0].StateName"
      ng-options="yourSelect3.StateName for yourSelect3 in requirements.Item2">  
</select>
<!-- for debugging --> {{ choosenValue }} <!-- should show a statename -->
```

else if you want the object as the choosenValue but display the statename as the options title use..

```
<select ng-model="choosenValue"
      class="form-control"
      ng-init="choosenValue=requirements.Item2[0]"
      ng-options="yourSelect3 as yourSelect3.StateName for yourSelect3 in requirements.Item2">  
</select>
<!-- for debugging --> {{ choosenValue | json }} <!-- should show the object -->
<!-- for debugging --> {{ choosenValue.StateName }} <!-- should show a statename -->
```

Comment: not worked for me . my code :`<select ng-model="yourSelect3"
                            class="form-control"
                            ng-init="yourSelect3=requirements.Item2[0].StateName"
                            ng-options="yourSelect3 as yourSelect3.StateName for yourSelect3 in requirements.Item2"></select>
`

Comment: OP's syntax for ng-options is correct : label for item in items is a valid structure; by default, ng-options binds the item if no select clause is given.

Comment: Check my rewrite.. sorry missed the ng-model related 2nd issue

Comment: For those who reads it and tries to understand. Two very misleading points: 1. result of `ng-init` is not used as selected item for `select`. The only way to influence what is preselected is to assign the value to `ng-model` variable; 2. there is no such thing as _temporary_ variable of `ng-options`. `ng-init` evaluates in `$scope` and any assignments to previously not existing variables create those variable in `$scope`